# jQuery $.each loop not executing

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the below code each loop is not getting executed. code above and below the loop is executed. Unable to figure out the reason.

```js
GM_xmlhttpRequest({
  method: "GET",
  url: link,
  synchronous: true,
  onload: function(response) {

    //console.log($(response.responseText).find( "#P16_STATUS2" ).text());
    var status = "NOT FOUND";
    if ($(response.responseText).find("#P16_STATUS2").size() === 1) {
      status = $(response.responseText).find("#P16_STATUS2").text();
      console.log("Status is " + status);
    } else if ($(response.responseText).find("#P16_STATUS3").size() === 1) {
      status = $(response.responseText).find("#P16_STATUS3").val();
      console.log("Status is " + status);
    }
    alert("one");
    //for (var i = 0; i < requestArray.length; i++) {      
    $.each(requestArray, function(key, value) {
      alert("in each");
      console.log("inside for");
      if (key === val) {
        console.log("request id found already present in array");
        return false; // <=== breaks out of the loop early
      } else {
        console.log("request id not found, Hence adding" + newArray[i]);
        var pusharr = [val + "-" + status];
        requestArray.push(pusharr);
        console.log("Updated Array is " + requestArray);
      }
    });


    alert("out");
    linkTag.attr("title", status);

  }
});
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Where does requestArray come from? I suspect it is empty or undefined.

Comment: Unrelated: `return false; // <=== breaks out of the loop early` that will not work the way you assume.

Comment: for the functionality you're going for, the original for loop would work better.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure `requestArray` is not empty. jQuery will not execute the each function on an empty object/array.